# Promise.all does not wait for nested promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm new to Promises and can't get a handle on how they work. I have a list of MySQL statements I would like to complete before returning their values. I tried to use `Promise.all` to add each statement as a Promise, but `Promise.all` never waits for the nested Promise to complete. Similar questions on SO had problems like nor returning Promises, which is not my problem. If anyone could provide guidance I promise I'll be very grateful.

```
class Database {
    constructor( config ) {
        this.connection = mysql.createConnection( config );
    }
    query( sql, args ) {
        return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
            this.connection.query( sql, args, ( err, rows ) => {
                if ( err )
                    return reject( err );
                resolve( rows );
            } );
        } );
    }
    close() {
        return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
            this.connection.end( err => {
                if ( err )
                    return reject( err );
                resolve();
            } );
        } );
    }
}

function scanCountWrapper(resname, resProjectDict){
  var sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE resource = '" + resname + "'";
  database.query(sql).then( count => {  // query returns a Promise (see above function definition)
    return new Promise((resolve) => { // nested promise
      resProjectDict[resname] = count[0]["COUNT(*)"];
      resolve(count[0]["COUNT(*)"]);
    })
  })
}

function getAnyCount(latestResourceList, cb){
  var resProjectDict = {};
  var scanPromises = [];
  for (r=0;r<latestResourceList.length;r++){
      var resname = latestResourceList[r];
      console.log("resource is " + resname);
      scanPromises.push(scanCountWrapper(resname, resProjectDict)); //add Promise
  }
  Promise.all(scanPromises)
    .then((values) => { // this doesn't wait for the nested promises to finish executing
      console.log(resProjectDict); // EMPTY because nested promises have not exeecuted.
    })
}
```

---

EDIT

Sorry forgot to mention query is also returning a promise (I added that function above)

Comment: `scanCountWrapper` doesn't return anything, let alone a promise

Comment: you need to resolve scanCountWrapper

Comment: please see edit. thanks

Comment: wrap `database.query(sql).then(` into one **Promise** like `return new Promise((resolve1, reject1) => {..; ...; resolve1(count[0]["COUNT(*)"]);})`; in your codes, **return statement** inside the function=**scanCountWrapper**  is within Promise.then

Comment: sorry I dont understand. if you look at function definition of `query` it is already returning new Promise.

Comment: There is a `return` missing before `database.query(sql).then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing to `Promise.all()` an array of return values from `scanCountWrapper()`.  But `scanCountWrapper()` doesn't return anything, therefore you're just passing `Promise.all()` and array of `undefined` values.

Instead, you need to be passing it an array of promises.  So, `scanCountWrapper()` needs to return a promise that is connected to the asynchronous operations inside it.

You can do that like this by changing `database.query(...).then(...)` to `return database.query(...).then(...)`:

```
function scanCountWrapper(resname, resProjectDict){
  var sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE resource = '" + resname + "'";
  return database.query(sql).then( count => {
      resProjectDict[resname] = count[0]["COUNT(*)"];
      return count[0]["COUNT(*)"];
  });
}
```

In addition, the promise you were creating inside of your `.then()` handler was unnecessary.  You can just return a value directly from a `.then()` handler and that value will become the resolved value of the parent promise chain.